# Session Management in an android

Tags: android, authentication, retrofit, session-management

Can anybody suggest how to handle SessionManagement in an android app for a login screen after login I have 4 activities. on signing for different users different user's activity opens. I am getting 3 parameters from retrofit:- userId password and their designation in int(1,2,3,4) on getting different designations done of the 4 activities must open. please guide me how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use shared preference class of android and save your designation value in it. Then based on the value of designation you can check and navigate the users to the desired activity.